# Testing IAB returns "Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account"

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing

For the App I am working on I am using In App Purchases. I am now trying to test it but when I try to purchase something I get the error:

```
Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account
```

I already created a signed APK, uploaded it as Alpha to the Play Store. I also added my personal account (not my developer account) as alpha tester and as purchase tester in the Google Play Developer Console. I installed the signed APK on both my personal as my development phones but on both I get the error.

The only thing I haven't done is Publish the Alpha app in the Play Store. This is because our client doesn't have all the data to fill in at the Store Listing section. I have read that it is possible to test IAB without publishing the app.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake. It is required to publish the app now. After I did this and downloaded it from the (Alpha) Play store it all worked. Too bad I can't debug/log this. If someone has a solution for this, please let me know.